# problema con posicionamiento de pantalla cuando el teclado se activa con React native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, programación-móvil

Sucede que cuando se activa el teclado, parece que se coloca por encima de mi vista y esto oculta el input.

[image]

Comment: Ignoren el doble icono del carrito de compra

Comment: Nuestros amigos de React Native crearon [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html) para ayudarnos con esos dolores de cabeza ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render() {
    return (<KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={styles.container}
        behavior='position'
        keyboardVerticalOffset={32}>
{... tu vista ...}
</KeyboardAvoidingView>);
}
```

y a me funciona bien puedes jugar con el keyboardVerticalOffset con números positivos o negativos según te convenga